# Bookshelf's nested query

Tags: bookshelf.js

I'm trying to get the following query in bookshelf's, any ideas? (this query is working and returns the required result)

```
SELECT "restaurants".*, "meals".*, ( select count(*) from "public"."visitors" as "visitors" where "visitors"."meal_id" = "meals"."id") as "visitorsMealsCount" FROM "public"."restaurants" as "restaurants" inner join "public"."meals" as "meals" ON "meals"."restaurant_id" = "restaurants"."id" WHERE "restaurants"."id" = '123'
```

Another question, after I'm using belongsTo and hasMany (for example) i expected the return object will be similar to that

```
restaurants (obj)
   meals (obj)
   visitorsMealsCount (attribute)
```

Answer (score 0):

to me your SQL statement doesn't match the concept of an ORM tool like Bookshelf - it neither returns restaurants nor meals, but a grand mixture.

As to your second question: How about using `new Restaurant({id: '123'}).fetch({ withRelated: ['meals']})` ?

*visitorsMealsCount*: In the [documentation I see](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-belongsToMany)

```
adminAccounts: function() {
  return this.belongsToMany(Account).query({where: {access: 'admin'}});
},
```

so maybe

```
visitorsMealsCount: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(Visitor).count();
}
```

works? (I haven't tried it.)